# Micrometer's Gauge - update ratio

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datadog, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'm wondering what's the update ratio of gauge meter in micrometer:

```
List<String> list = registry.gauge("listGauge", Collections.emptyList(), new ArrayList<>(), List::size);
```

now let's say that list is changing sometimes often, sometimes stays without a change for a long time. How often `aList.size()` will be called?

***More general question:***

Is gauge a good pick for reporting DB table state every x seconds? I've a table with date column and want to configure alert when date is older than t seconds. That requires DB query each time, so I don't want to be called too often. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer:

There is configuration property [polling-frequency](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/b8f105674f3f94e1d8614799fe9a26c88fb7ff7e/implementations/micrometer-registry-statsd/src/main/java/io/micrometer/statsd/StatsdConfig.java#L103), so configure it like this:

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.polling-frequency: 30s
```

and gauge seems to be a good match for reporting DB table state.